# vim: Change color of tab bar

Tags: vim

How can I change the color of vim's tab bar and its font?

I also notice that the colors differ between gVim and vim opened in a terminal, so I'd like to adjust that.

I had a look in my color schemes and vim's documentation but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it!

```
hi TabLine      guifg=#333 guibg=#222 gui=none ctermfg=254 ctermbg=238 cterm=none
hi TabLineSel   guifg=#666 guibg=#222 gui=bold ctermfg=231 ctermbg=235 cterm=bold
hi TabLineFill  guifg=#999 guibg=#222 gui=none ctermfg=254 ctermbg=238 cterm=none
```